# REST API separate endpoint for search and filter

Tags: javascript, rest

I've made a webapp for a simple marketplace. I have three different functions: searching, filtering, filtering by keys. Each of these functions contains different query parameters. My problem is that how should I separate these endpoints in a rest way?

For example, this is my endpoint for searching:

```
API.get('/product/',{params:querydata})
```

On search I get these query parameters:

```
{
  skip: '0',
  limit: '8',
  searchTerm: '',
  filters: '{"minPrice":1,"maxPrice":250000}'
}
```

But when I use the filter function I will have something like this for query parameters:

```
{
Color:'Red',
Type:'Car'
}
```

And when I use the keyfilter function I will have

```
{
filters:['red','black','bmw']
}
```

What is the correct approach for this? Before I used post to differentiate the filters and the search, but now I'm trying to transform into a rest api. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? If you are using some library (Angular, React) - it will build Query string from your params. If not - you may need to generate Query string your self. In any event, it will be `/product/?skip=0&limit=8&minPrice=1...` Then on the server side you will have to make sense of the parameters, like how to combine `'red','black','bmw'` with **AND** and **OR**

Comment: You could add another param such as `type:'search'` then have different logic based on the various types

Comment: @Felix The main problem is that my query parameters are dynamically changes, so on my server side I don't know how to refer to that parameters. But maybe I'm understanding something wrong, indeed I use React with a Node.js/Express backend, if you can provide some examples I would appreciate it.  @ charlietfl The type could be a good idea, I thought something same before.

Comment: Query parameters are *always* dynamically generated - so it's not a problem in itself. My stack is different (Angular / .NET) - so I can't give an answer. But probably you need to rework the question. "This is my client-side React code; this is my server-side Express code; and this is the problem". And consequentially, your tags will be different as well.

Comment: @MrNobody - What does your Node/Express GET route look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that how should I separate these endpoints in a rest way?

REST doesn't have "endpoints".  It has [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and [resource identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

> What is the correct approach for this?

For all of these, you should use GET (the semantics of the request are effectively read only), with the parameters you need embedded in the URI *somewhere*.  It's largely up to you where in the URI the parameter should be.

On the web, we usually want to choose identifiers that make it easy to support a web search form, which usually means describing the parameters as a list of key value pairs, so you end up with something like:

```
GET /product/?Color=Red&Type=Car
```

If you don't need web forms that "just work", then you have more options for how to construct your resource identifiers.  Your best bets will be those described by [RFC 6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570), because general purpose libraries that support URI Templates are widely available.

From a REST perspective, the actual spelling of the URI doesn't matter very much, so you can choose a spelling that best fits your needs.  There are trade offs; you may find that your current framework prefers some spellings to others, but a different spelling might be better for operators reading access logs, or for creating a relative reference from one resource to another.

Lots of possibilities that are all *fine*, so long as the spellings are consistent with the [production rules described in RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A), and you don't try to use the same identifier for two different resources.